# Dynamic and Static Leases on ISC DHCP

Tags: debian, networking, raspbian, isc-dhcpd

I'm running ISC DHCPd on Raspbian. I want to set up my server so that all addresses in `192.168.0.0/24` are static leases, and all in `192.168.1.0/24` are dynamic leases. I'd like the two to share the 192.168.0.0/23 subnet.

**Clarification:** Basically, I want a single DHCP server to handle DHCP for the entire `192.168.0.0/23` subnet. If a device that requests an IP has a `host` entry defined in `dhcpd.conf`, it will assign it the IP address that is specified. If it does not, it will assign an address in the range `192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.254`. For simplicity, I have limited all of my static leases to reside in the range `192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.254`.

I have my server configured as so:

```
option domain-name "home";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.3;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
host mightyturing{ hardware ethernet 10:bf:48:87:74:a2; fixed-address 192.168.0.64; }
host beastnugget{ hardware ethernet 34:e6:d7:52:1e:e4; fixed-address 192.168.0.65; }
host ... (about 50 more static leases)
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers 192.168.0.1;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.3, 1.1.1.1;
        option domain-name "home";
        option subnet-mask 255.255.254.0;
        ddns-updates off;
}
```

When I try to start the service it whines:

```
Nov 17 17:45:26 raspberrypi dhcpd[681]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.64 from 10:bf:48:87:74:a2 via eth0
Nov 17 17:45:26 raspberrypi dhcpd[681]: DHCPACK on 192.168.0.64 to 10:bf:48:87:74:a2 via eth0
Nov 17 17:45:59 raspberrypi dhcpd[681]: Dynamic and static leases present for 192.168.0.64.
Nov 17 17:45:59 raspberrypi dhcpd[681]: Remove host declaration mightyturing or remove 192.168.0.64
Nov 17 17:45:59 raspberrypi dhcpd[681]: from the dynamic address pool for 192.168.0.0/23
```

... and since my lease pool is `192.168.1.0/24`... I'm pretty sure that means that `192.168.0.64` is not in the pool. So why is ISC not recognizing this? Why is it complaining about a range that I have not instructed it to issue dynamic IPs for?

**Also:**

When I change the range to issue dynamic IPs on the `10.0.0.0/24` range (to test ISC's sanity), but keep the static leases in `192.168.0.0/24`, it still complains about `192.168.0.0/23` so what is going on?  Where, precisely, did I ask it to hand out 192.168.0.0/23 addresses?

```
option domain-name "home";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.3;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
host mightyturing{ hardware ethernet 10:bf:48:87:74:a2; fixed-address 192.168.0.64; }
host beastnugget{ hardware ethernet 34:e6:d7:52:1e:e4; fixed-address 192.168.0.65; }
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.254 {
        option routers 10.0.0.1;
        option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
        option domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1;
        option domain-name "home";
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        ddns-updates off;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it is a typo, but you write to have `192.168.0.0/24` and `192.168.1.0/24` networks, but from the config and log files they are `/23` and are overlapping. You might want to add the output of `ip route` of your dhcp server.

Comment: I want traffic to cross between them, but I want to segregate based on lease type. Hand out static leases on `192.168.0.0/24` and dynamic leases on `192.168.1.0/24` but have them share the `192.168.0.0/23` subnet for routing. Is that not how I have it set up?

Comment: Nope, this is not how IP networks work. You have to separate the networks so they do not overlap. Then set up routing between those two subnets.

Comment: Ok, so if I wanted to reserve part of the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet (say, 192.168.0.16-192.168.0.31)  for only static leases and use the rest for dynamic leases, could I do that?

Comment: Sure, just use `range 192.168.0.16 192.168.0.31;` in your subnet declaration to limit the dynamic leases, configure your other hosts with the `host ...` directive and be sure to leave out any other IP addresses that are assigned statically like the IP address of the DHCP server itself.

Comment: @Thomas I was able to get my original idea working with your suggestions. I used `subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.254.0` and `range 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.254` and got it working. If you want to put up an answer I'll accept it, I don't want to take credit for your help.